# R : doesn't recognise column in a new table

Tags: r, dplyr

This is part of an online course I am doing, R for data analysis.

A tibble is created using the group_by and summarise functions on the diamonds data set - the new tibble indeed exists and looks as you would expect, I checked. Now a bar plot has to be created using these summary values in the new tibble, but it gives me all sorts of errors associated with not recognising the columns. 
I transformed the tibble into a data frame, and still get the same problem.

Here is the code:

```
diamonds_by_color <- group_by(diamonds, color)
diamonds_mp_by_color <- summarise(diamonds_by_color, mean_price = mean(price))
diamonds_mp_by_color <- as.data.frame(diamonds_mp_by_color)
colorcounts <- count(diamonds_by_color$mean_price)
colorbarplot <- barplot(diamonds_by_color$mean_price, names.arg = diamonds_by_color$color, 
                           main = "Average price for different colour diamonds")
```

The error I get when running the function count is:

> Error in UseMethod("summarise_") : 
>     no applicable method for 'summarise_' applied to an object of class "NULL"
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>   Unknown or uninitialised column: 'mean_price'.

It's probably something trivial but I have been reading quite a lot and tried a few things and can't figure it out. Any help will be super appreciated :)

Comment: I don't think you need the third line of code. And also 'count' takes a df and a column. count(df, col). It is better if you don't assign with <- until you like the result...

Comment: `diamonds_by_color` never has `mean_price` assigned to it ... it is calculated from that frame but then assigned to `diamonds_mp_by_color`.

Comment: The output of line 2 is a data frame, you don't need to make it a data frame in line 3...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `diamonds_by_color` never has `mean_price` assigned to it.

Your last two lines of code work if you reference `diamonds_mp_by_color` instead:

```r
colorcounts <- count(diamonds_mp_by_color, mean_price)
barplot(diamonds_mp_by_color$mean_price,
        names.arg=diamonds_mp_by_color$color,
        main="Average price for different colour diamonds")
```

Comment: For the record, Isquare1, I agree with [@smci's assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57048022/3358272) that a more-idiomatic way to do this would be to use a pipe of verb-functions, ala `%>%`. It's style, certainly, but it is the "tidyverse norm".

Answer (score 0):

Best dplyr idiom is not to declare a temporary result for each operation. Just do one big pipe; also the `%>%` notation is clearer because you don't have to keep specifying which dataframe as the first arg in each operation:

```
diamonds %>%
    group_by(color) %>%
    summarise(mean_price = mean(price)) %>%
    tally() %>% # equivalent to n() on a group
    # may need ungroup() %>%
    barplot(mean_price, names.arg = color, 
        main = "Average price for different colour diamonds")
```

(Something like that. You can assign the output of the pipe before the barplot if you like. I'm transiting through an airport so I can't check it in R.)

Comment: If you're talking idioms (and I agree with encouragement to pipe things), then this code can easily fail on the console with `Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "         %>%"`. It is often preferred to have the `%>%` pipe *after* a command, not leading on the line. Though for some applications it might be mostly style, I think having code work in a script but not in a console is fragile.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to summarise the price by color using `dplyr` and piping straight to a barplot using `ggplot2`.

```r
diamonds %>% group_by(color) %>% 
  summarise(mean.price=mean(price,na.rm=1)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(color,mean.price)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

[image: Summary barplot]